# Thinkpad T480 Linux Battery performance

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery, thinkpad

I recently bought a used Thinkpad T480. It has two batteries. New version of this laptop are supposed to have an 17-hour battery life. I don't expect Linux to necessarily match that, but even still I'm having odd behavior.

My Linux system (Ubuntu 22.04.1, running Kubuntu with 5.15.0-58-generic).

1st, when I unplug from power, it takes about 2 or 4 minutes for the system to even ***recognize*** it is unplugged and switch. This isn't just a KDE problem, since upower on the console has the same issue. Any thoughts on why this is so?

2nd, is battery performance themselves. I know these batteries are used, but their performance is WAAAY worse than I expect. I use the watch + upower command to check details:

`upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`

```
native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               SMP
  model:                01AV421
  serial:               1660
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Tue 17 Jan 2023 04:08:18 PM PST (88 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              20.99 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         22.39 Wh
    energy-full-design:  24 Wh
    energy-rate:         6.33 W
    voltage:             12.197 V
    charge-cycles:       91
    time to empty:       3.3 hours
    percentage:          93%
    capacity:            93.2917%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
```

`upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1`

```
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               Celxpert
  model:                01AV424
  serial:               516
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Tue 17 Jan 2023 04:10:18 PM PST (90 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               fully-charged
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              19.27 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         19.27 Wh
    energy-full-design:  24.05 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             12.675 V
    charge-cycles:       213
    percentage:          100%
    capacity:            80.1247%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'
```

When it is plugged it, upower initially estimates **10.0 hours** of battery performance. When I unplug it, then the estimate drops to **5.0 hours**, then a few minutes later, it drops to **3.0 hours**, then it jumps back up to **4.0 hours**. Finally it settles around the 3.3-hour mark. Meanwhile the KDE power icon estimates **7.5 hours**.

A causal usage test confirms I get only about 3.3-hours of battery before the whole system loses power. (Also KDE does NOT warn me about power getting low, but that maybe another story.). I don't see any evidence that it even draws power from the second-battery (BAT1).

Is there anything I can do software-wise to improve this? This battery life is atrocious.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that a quick way of extending battery life on laptops running linux is by installing [TLP](https://linrunner.de/tlp/index.html). It should extend your battery life a noticable amount.

Comment: For a Thinkpad you should also install tlp-rdw

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I have a dual battery i7 touchscreen T480 that I bought new and have run dual boot Win/Ubuntu since new (with TLP and latest firmware installed). The battery life you mentioned is what I’ve consistently seen from it since it was new, in either windows or Ubuntu